# How to iterate over a list in an async function in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I am try to display a list of contacts in Svelte. I need to do this in an async function as I need extra data from the database. It gives the error

> {#each} only iterates over array-like objects.

If I remove the *async* it works, but of course I have no access to the extra data.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d86b320d5ec44051b46e41f3f8d0405f?version=3.46.6)

**App.svelte**

```
{#each contacts_list as contact}
    <div>{contact}</div>
{/each}

<script>
    import { contacts, user_contacts } from './data-store'
    $: contacts_list = getContacts($contacts)

async function getContacts() {
        let contact_list = []
        console.log(isIterable($user_contacts))
        if (isIterable($user_contacts)) {
            for (let contact of $user_contacts) {
                contact_list.push(contact);
            };
        };
        return contact_list;
    };


    function isIterable (value) {
        return Symbol.iterator in Object(value);
    };
</script>
```

**data-store.js**

```
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

    export let contacts = writable([]);
    export let user_contacts = writable(['a', 'b']);
```

Answer (score 2):

An async function in javascript always returns a promise.
You have to await the promise for it`s result.

```
<script>
  import { contacts, user_contacts } from "./data-store";
  $: contacts_promise = getContacts($contacts);

  const getContacts = async () => {
    let contact_list = [];
    console.log(isIterable($user_contacts));
    if (isIterable($user_contacts)) {
      for (let contact of $user_contacts) {
        contact_list.push(contact);
      }
    }
    return contact_list;
  };

  function isIterable(value) {
    return Symbol.iterator in Object(value);
  }
</script>

{#await contacts_promise}
  <p>...waiting</p>
{:then contacts_list}
  {#each contacts_list as contact}
    <div>{contact}</div>
  {/each}
{:catch error}
  <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

This code solves your request. But i guess your overall structure is faulty. You want the async function called whenever `$contacts` changes, but then you use a different variable `$user_contacts`. I dont know the content of your data-stores but the following example should lead you to a svelte way on how to tackle the issue:

```
<script>
  import { user_contacts } from "./data-store";
</script>

{#each $user_contacts || [] as contact}
  <div>{contact}</div>
{/each}
```

Comment: Thanks - yes muddled design :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the block in an `{#await}`, e.g.

```html
{#await contacts_list then list}
    {#each list as contact}
        <div>{contact}</div>
    {/each}
{/await}
```

(Might want to add a `{:catch ...}` if you need error handling in the HTML output.)

Also, creating an array from a synchronous iterable can be simplified:

```js
if (isIterable($user_contacts))
    contact_list = [...$user_contacts];
```